# infinite redirect loop + php not echoing a variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql, session, authentication

I created a login system where after login, the user will be redirected to `profile.php`. In the `profile.php` page, the heading will say `Welcome [username]`

Session.php:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
$db = mysqli_select_db($connection, "id2290767_wp");

session_start();
$user_check = isset($_SESSION['login_user']);

$ses_sql = mysqli_query($connection, "select name from login where name='$user_check'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ses_sql);
$login_session = $row['name'];
if(!empty($login_session)) {
    mysqli_close($connection);
    header('Location: members.php');
}
```

profile.php (the one with the greetings)

```
<?php
include('session.php');

if(!isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
     header("location: profile.php");
}
?>

<h1>Welcome <i><?php echo $login_session; ?></h1>
```

The signin.php linked with the login form in members.php:

```
session_start(); // Starting Session
$error = ''; // Variable To Store Error Message
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if(empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
        $error = "Username or Password is invalid";
    } else {
        // Define $username and $password
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        // Establishing Connection with Server by passing server_name, user_id and password as a parameter
        $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
        // To protect MySQL injection for Security purpose
        $username = stripslashes($username);
        $password = stripslashes($password);
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $username);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $password);
        // Selecting Database
        $db = mysqli_select_db($connection, "id2290767_wp");
        // SQL query to fetch information of registerd users and finds user match.
        $query = mysqli_query($connection, "select * from login where password='$password' AND name='$username'");
        $rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
        if($rows == 1) {
            $_SESSION['login_user'] = $username; // Initializing Session
            header("location: profile.php"); // Redirecting To Other Page
        } else {
            $error = "Username or Password is invalid";
        }
        mysqli_close($connection); // Closing Connection
    }
}
```

members.php:

```
<?php
include('signin.php'); // Includes Login Script

if(isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
     header("location: profile.php");
}
```

But I get no text in the PHP page. It just says "Welcome".

What did I do wrong?

EDIT: Getting infinite loop after changing

```
$user_check = isset($_SESSION['login_user']);
```

to

```
$user_check=isset($_SESSION['login_user']) ? $_SESSION['login_user'] : "";
```

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says **[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)**. Learn about [Prepared Statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even **[escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)** is not safe!

Comment: your welcome page is  `members.php` ? am i right?

Comment: no, the welcome page is at profile.php, the memebrs.php has the signin form and redirects to profile.php if theres a session

Comment: then you have some `$_POST` or `$_GET` value on `members.php` page? isn't it (if you are coming through a login form)?

Comment: added whole code

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use **PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)** (`password_hash()` and `password_verify()`) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). **It is not necessary** to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527) or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so _changes_ the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: Not only are you vulnerable to SQL Injection, but you are _also_ storing passwords with plain-text. I would under **no circumstance** want to use your application for any reason as you aren't even attempting to make it secure ;)

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton thanks, im just in the process of learning now, Thanks for reminding me about security, ill get in that later

Comment: @TheZZGamerz It's incredibly easy to use both of these functions, I don't recommend putting it off at all. Learn the correct way first, instead of learning the wrong way and going back later. I recommend using PDO for prepared statements as it is also incredibly easy.

Comment: @TheZZGamerz : Your Problem Solved?

Comment: @NanaPartykar no.. still getting redirect loops

Comment: In profile.php, If session is not set. Then, why are you redirecting it to profile.php? It should go to signin.php page @TheZZGamerz

Comment: @NanaPartykar im a newbie in sql and php. didnt get the answer. also why didnt the redirect loop occur before your code was applied?

Comment: See. Redirect loop is not because of my answer. I corrected your mistake. Now, it all depends upon your logic how you implemented it. Untill and unless I see your full code. I can't understand the logic fully. What I found in **profile.php** is: If session is not set, either it should go to signin page or logout the user. @TheZZGamerz

Comment: thats the full code here. the first part is the session.php. its called on the profile.php and the signin.php is included in the members.php (the page with the login form?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150803/discussion-between-nana-partykar-and-the-zz-gamerz).

Answer (score 2):

The [isset ()](http://www.w3resource.com/php/function-reference/isset.php) function is used to check whether a variable is set or not.

Change

```
$user_check=isset($_SESSION['login_user']);
```

To

```
$user_check=isset($_SESSION['login_user']) ? $_SESSION['login_user'] : "";
```

Comment: I would mention that the problem is that OP is setting `$user_check` to true/false as that is not very clear from your answer (to a newbie developer).

Comment: i think it should work, but im stuck in an infinite redirect loop now,

Comment: It will work. Infinite redirect loop is because of too many 'check session condition'. According to your given code, this was the problem. But, you need to provide more details. So that, we can understand the functionality and can suggest few suggestions @TheZZGamerz